# Unable to display dropdown menubar due to some error in css position

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

I was writing a code to create a navigationbar menu via css-Dropdown but i'm stuck here at this point. Whenever I click on "Dropdown" i'm not able to get desired menubar however on removing "position: relative" at pointed position gives correct result. What's the problem with my original code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #333;
        }
        li{
            float: left;
        }
        li a, .dropbutton{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            display:  inline-block;
            border: none; /* x */
            text-align: center;
        }
        li a:hover , .dropdown:hover .dropbutton
        {
            background-color:black;

        }
```

if i remove "position: relative" from below then i'm able to get navbar menu

```
        .dropdown{
           position: relative;  /* remove */
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .dropdown_content {
            display: none;
            background-color: #444;
         position: absolute;
            color: white;
            box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
            text-align: center; 
            z-index: 1;            
        }
        .dropdown_content a{
             color: black;
             padding: 12px 16px;
             text-decoration: none;
             display: block;
        }
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown_content{
            display: block;
        }
        .dropdown_content a:hover{
            background-color: silver;
        }

        </style>
</head>

<body>


    <ul>
        <li><a href="#jfjkwj">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#jfjkwj">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#jfjkwj">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#jfjkwj">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbutton">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown_content">
                <a href="#nkkje">okay</a>
                <a href="#nkkje">okay</a>
                <a href="#nkkje">okay</a>
            </div>
        </li>
            </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `overflow:hidden` from the `<ul>`, thats what is hidding the dropdown content, and use `display:inline-block` on `<li>` instead of float

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
}

li a,
.dropbutton {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  /* x */
  text-align: center;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbutton {
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown_content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown_content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown_content a:hover {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#jfjkwj">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#jfjkwj">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#jfjkwj">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#jfjkwj">Home</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbutton">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown_content">
      <a href="#nkkje">okay</a>
      <a href="#nkkje">okay</a>
      <a href="#nkkje">okay</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but what's the problem with float: left? i mean why is it wrong to write "float: left" here?

Comment: @Jayesh using float on li will make the parent(ul) have no space, so you will have to set the width and the height to make it show, thats why you added overflow:hidden but that will cause to hid the dropdown

Comment: i agree totally with you but if we take a case like this /* https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar */ . no position is given to ul/li.dropdown i.e. there default position:static will come in use but as soon as i try position:relative the navbar disappears !!! what's the problem here in this specific case?

Comment: The problem is that you used `position:absolute` on dropdown_content which will require the parent (li) to have `position:relative;` so its a deffirent case here

Comment: ,thanks for understanding that case! and so u mean that if i add position:relative to my code it'll work? but it's not working that way too. Now if u say that issue is with overflow:hidden then why doesn't that issue came in case of *absence of position in li*?

Comment: because absolute positin will make the element go out of the flow of the document and the space it takes will be ignored by the other dom element.. !

Comment: thanks a lot ! please correct me if i'm wrong somewhere - In my acual code _position_ of *.dropdown_content* was _absolute_ and that of *.dropdown* was _relative_ now since ".dropdown_content" comes out of the main container so it got hidden but when we take the case as in *w3schools* in that case *.dropdown_content*  was positioned relative to our documented body not to "ul" so we were able to view it even in the presence of *overflow:hidden* ? Am i thinking the right way?..

Comment: Yes, i believe that is the case

Answer (score 0):

You have `overflow:hidden` on your `ul` selector, which means nothing will show outside of the `ul`.